# Svelte - UI does not get rendered which data I fetch from API

Tags: fetch, svelte, sveltekit

This is my script-tag:

```
<script lang="ts">

    import Card from "../../components/Card.svelte";
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

        let show_all = false;
        let data: Array<{id: number, image_url: string, description: string, link: string, title: string}> = [];

        onMount(async () => {
            try {
                console.log(data)
                let response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/entries");
                data = await response.json();
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });

    const  getData = async () => {
        console.log(data)
    if (!show_all) {
        return data.slice(0, 12);
    } else {
        return data;
    }
</script>
```

I render the data like this:

```
{#await getData()}
    <p>...waiting</p>
{:then array}

    {#each array as item (item.id)}
        <Card image_url={item.image_url} description={item.description} link={item.link}  title={item.title} />
    {/each}
{:catch error}
    <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

Fetching the data from the API works fine, but it seems to `getData()` function works with the empty array, not with `data` after it has been updated.
What am I doing wrong here? I thought using the `onMount` hook would guarantee that the UI gets rendered after the data was fetched.

Can anyone help me to fix this

The order is also logged here:
getdata
hook

hook should be called before getData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, as you mentioned, the order. `getData()` runs before the `onMount` callback. I assume `waiting...` should be shown while the data is fetched and the displayed data should also react to changes of `show_all`?

Here's one way in case `data` isn't otherwise needed inside the script tag

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Card from "../../components/Card.svelte";

    let show_all = false;
        
    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            let response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/entries");
            return await response.json();
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
</script>

{#await getData()}
    <p>...waiting</p>
{:then data}
    {@const dataToBeShown = show_all ? data : data.slice(0, 12)}
    {#each dataToBeShown as item (item.id)}
        <Card {...item} />
    {/each}
{:catch error}
    <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

in case it is

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Card from "../../components/Card.svelte";

    let show_all = false;
    let data: Array<{id: number, image_url: string, description: string, link: string, title: string}> = [];
    
    $: dataToBeShown = show_all ? data : data.slice(0, 12)

    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            let response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/entries");
            data = await response.json();
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
</script>

{#await getData()}
    <p>...waiting</p>
{:then _}
    {#each dataToBeShown as item (item.id)}
        <Card {...item} />
    {/each}
{:catch error}
    <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

Since the property names seem to match >>  `<Card {...item} />`